# Detecting if elements are wrapping using jQuery/getClientRects()

Tags: jquery

I need to apply a jQuery function to a `div` only if the `span` items within it are wrapping. I'm trying to determine this with `getClientRects()` but it's always returning one line. You can see this in the snippet below. Is there anything obviously wrong here?

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var minimized_elements = $('.countLines');
  var maxLines = 1;
  
  minimized_elements.each(function() {
    var lineCount = $(this)[0].getClientRects().length;
    alert(lineCount);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #898989;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countLines">
  <span>item 1</span><span>item 2</span><span>item 3</span><span>item 4</span><span>item 5</span><span>item 6</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you require you can instead retrieve a unique Set of the top positions of the `span` elements. From there you can count the number of values within that Set; it will be the number of lines the spans cross. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let lines = new Set($('.countLines span').map((i, el) => $(el).offset().top).get()).size;
  console.log(lines);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #898989;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countLines">
  <span>item 1</span><span>item 2</span><span>item 3</span><span>item 4</span><span>item 5</span><span>item 6</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Rory!  That's exactly the kind of thing I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: In pure Javascript.

This is done by getting the total width of all span elements. Then we compare it to the parent's width. If the parent's width is less than the total width, we determine it's wrapping.

```js
var el = document.querySelector(".countLines"),
    span = el.querySelectorAll("span"),
    totalWidth = 0;

span.forEach(span => totalWidth += span.clientWidth);

if (el.clientWidth < totalWidth) {
  console.log("Wrapping!");
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #898989;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="countLines">
  <span>item 1</span><span>item 2</span><span>item 3</span><span>item 4</span><span>item 5</span><span>item 6</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks appreciated you writing this.  For the record, I did ask for an example using jQuery syntax which is why I awarded to Rory but thanks again anyhow.